# Getting errors of kind invalid use of incomplete type 'struct node'

Tags: c++

`#include<iostream>`
`#include<string>`
`#include<algorithm>`
`using namespace std;`
`class sequence{`

```
   struct node{
       string name;
       string data;
       struct node * next;};
    sequence();
   ~sequence();
    void print(struct node *);
    struct node *sortlist(struct node *);
    struct node *deletenode(struct node *, string);
    struct node *searchnode(struct node *, string);
    struct node *insertnode(struct node *, string);};
```

`void print(struct node *st){` //method to print the linked list

```
while(st!=0){
    cout<<st->data<<endl;
    st=st->next;}}
```

`struct node *deletenode(struct node *st, string x){`//to delete a node containing element x

```
    struct node *s1=st, *t,*ptr;
    string m=x;
    ptr=st;
    if (s1==0)// if linked list is empty {
        cout<<"linkedlist empty"<<endl;}
    else if(s1->next==0)//if linked list contains only one element
    {
        if(s1->data==m)
        {
        free(s1);
        s1=0;}
        else
        cout<<m<<"is not in the list."<<endl;
    }
    else if(s1->next!=0&&s1->data==m)
    {
        t=s1->next;
        free(s1);
        s1=t;

     }
    else
    {
        while(s1->data!=m&&s1->next!=0)
        {
            t=s1;
            s1=s1->next;
        }
        if(s1->data==m)
        {

            t->next=s1->next;
            free(s1);
            s1=t;
        }
        else
        cout<<m<<"is not in the list."<<endl;

    }
    return(ptr);        
}

int main(){

sequence obj=new sequence();
struct node *root1, *root2, *root3, *s, *p,*t;
string v;
root1= new node;
root2= new node;
root3= new node;
s=root1;
root1->next=root2;
root2->next=root3;
root3->next=0;
root1->data="man";//data in the nodes of linked list 
root2->data="aan";
root3->data="van";
root1->name="1";
root2->name="2";
root3->name="3";
    cout<<"enter the string :";
    cin>>v;
    cout<<endl;
    p=obj.deletenode(s, v);// delete node function call
    obj.print(p);

return(0);}
```

Problem 1: when i am running this code, it executes with bug in deletenode method where it is not deleting the first element of linked list but deleting every other element.Please enlighten me where i am getting wrong in the code.

Problem 2: I was trying to create a class with all above mention methods, a constructor and a destructor but when i am running this code i am getting errors like **"invalid use of incomplete type 'struct node'"**.I am new to the concept of classes kindly guide me where i am getting wrong in this code.

Apologies for no proper formatting.
looking for a positive reply.

Comment: sorry but seems that noone wants to understand your 1000 lines of code. Please make a simpler example for the question (and the answer) to be useful to all.

Comment: ^In other words: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: Maks, read [ask].  You need to provide an [mcve] for people to work with.  In this instance, I would stress "Minimal".  You should also put the actual error output into your question when you want help debugging.

Comment: And when you make a smaller version of the problem fix your code formatting.

Comment: if whole code is not there then how come u'll understand what error i am getting. i provided whole code just to make it easier to test and comment.

Comment: _"Apologies for no proper formatting. looking for a positive reply."_ Proper formatting first. Positive reply second.

Comment: _"if whole code is not there then how come u'll understand what error i am getting. i provided whole code just to make it easier to test and comment."_ You did not read the link you were given. An MCVE _is_ "whole code" that fully reproduces the problem and contains all necessary information ... but it's not your original, real-world code, that contains 990 completely irrelevant lines. Read again about constructing [MCVE]s. The other reason we require it is because if you don't have an MCVE then there's no way you've properly debugged the problem yourself yet, just making us do it for you.

Comment: Although the compilation error looks fairly obvious to me, out of principle I'll wait until you learn how to post a [mcve], instead of expecting everyone else on stackoverflow.com to debug your own code for you.

Comment: Is there is some error in declaration of class or in definition function?? tried to minimize it as much as possible as i can..

Comment: @Maks 1st: What you posted isn't a [MCVE] still. 2nd: The most common situations where you may get that kind of errors are 1. You forgot to `#include` the header containing the declaration. 2. Your headers are included in a circular manner 3. Some header guard was copied accidentally to another header file and you forgot to change it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But when I am running this method in another program without classes it's executing. I am unable to understand whether there's a fault in class declaration or in method definition??

Comment: @Maks So you thoroughly checked none of these common reasons I mentioned does apply?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes i thoroughly checked none of the above mentioned reasons does apply.

Answer (score -1):

well you are not supposed to define a whole Structure within the class definition 
, instead of doing this define the structure publicly and include its instance within the class . Hope this Helps

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct node{             //structure definition outside the class
   string name;
   string data;
   struct node * next;
};
class sequence{

node node1;        //define a node variable 
sequence();
~sequence();
void print(struct node *);
struct node *sortlist(struct node *);
struct node *deletenode(struct node *, string);
struct node *searchnode(struct node *, string);
struct node *insertnode(struct node *, string);};enter code here
```

Comment: "well you are not supposed to define a whole Structure within the class definition" this statement needs clarification.

Comment: you need to define everything before you use it within a program But while defining a class you are including instance of certain data types as its member , for example if you write 'int x ' within a class def. then you are defining an instance of integer datatype as class member . Since while you are defining a new structure ,you are making a user defined datatype and to include this datatype in your class you must use its instance i.e its object